# Удалить строку содержащую максимальный элемент диагонали.

Tags: c#, массивы

Пожалуйста, помогите определить строку, в которой находится максимальный элемент диагонали или хотя бы ткните носом в ошибку, которую я допускаю. Битый час корплю над работой. У меня всегда удаляется последняя строка.

```
namespace App7
{
    class Program
    {
        public static int MaxDiagonalElement(int[,] matrix)
        {
            int max = int.MinValue;
            int n = (int)Math.Sqrt(matrix.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (matrix[i, i] > max)
                {
                    max = matrix[i, i];
                }
            }
            return max;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[,] B = new int[5, 5];
            int[,] C = new int[6, 6];
            int[,] B1 = new int[4, 5];
            int[,] C1 = new int[5, 6];
            int n = 0, MaxElement, index = 0;

            Random Rnd = new Random();

            Console.WriteLine("Matrix B");
            Console.WriteLine();

            for (int i = 0; i < B.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < B.GetLength(1); k++)
                {
                    B[i, k] = Rnd.Next(20);
                    Console.Write(B[i, k] + "\t ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            //
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
                {
                }
                if (MaxDiagonalElement(B) == MaxDiagonalElement(B))
                    n = i;

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                if (i == n)
                    continue;
                for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
                {
                    B[index, k] = B[i, k];
                }
                index++;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
                {
                    Console.Write(B[i, k] + "\t ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Matrix C");
            Console.WriteLine();
            /*
            for (int i = 0; i < C.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < C.GetLength(1); k++)
                {
                    C[i, k] = Rnd.Next(20);
                    Console.Write(C[i, k] + "\t ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }*/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Для начала, почему `int[,]`? Пользуйтесь нормальными контейнерами: `List<List<int>>`.

Comment: @VladD, подобный образ записи пока не выучил (

Comment: Что означает условие

    if (MaxDiagonalElement(B) == MaxDiagonalElement(B))

? Не похоже на правильное.

Comment: Правильный код был бы такой:

    var diag = M.Select((row, i) => row[i]);
    var maxVal = diag.Max();
    var maxRowIndices = diag.Select((val, i) => (val == maxVal ? i : -1).Where(i => i >= 0);

---
Учите контейнеры. Удалить строку из массива **невозможно**.

Comment: @VladD, тут я хотел поставить условие, что максимальный элемент диагонали найден, при этом запомнить номер строки. Но к сожалению ничего более корректного в голову не пришло.

Comment: @Sier: я надеюсь, вы понимаете, что это условие всегда есть true?

Comment: @VladD, случайно удалил свой коментарий. Само собой я понимаю ) В первой строчке происходит перебор значений, во второй, выбирает максимальное, что присходит в третьей, не разберу условия. Можете обьяснить в двух словах ?

Comment: @VladD, теперь я совсем непонимаю как использовать код...

Comment: @Sier: первая строчка вычисляет диагональ. Вторая считает максимальное значение. Третья посложнее: она для элементов диагонали, равных макс. значению, запоминает индекс, а для остальных -1. А потом отфильтровывает отрицательные значения.

Comment: простой совет не глядя в ваш код. 1) запустите программу в режиме отладки и пошагово выполните код, смотря что у вас происходит. 2) предупреждаю, что Random класс нужно создавать с привязкой на Environment.TickCount. Удачи!

Comment: @semenvx27, класс Random не нужно создаваь с привязкой на Environment.TickCount, это и так делается дефолтным конструктором.